# Finding matching dictionary elements within two different lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Say i have two lists of dictionaries

```
masterSensor = [dict.fromkeys(['MasterKey', 'ItemType', 'ItemK'])]
sensor = [dict.fromkeys(['SensorK', 'SensorId'])]
```

And I wanted to merge the two dictionary elements that have the same value for the two keys ItemK and SensorK. The new dictionary would only need to contain masterkey and SensorID.

Im sure there is something more efficent than doing a double for loop?

```
for ik in masterSensor:
    for sk in sensor:
         if ik['ItemK'] == sk['SensorK']:
                newDict.append({'MasterKey' : ik['MasterKey'], 'SensorId' : sk['SensorId']})
                #sensor.remove(sk)      this ends up removing every other item 
                #masterSensor.remove(ik) this ends up removing every other item
```

Also im open to feedback, incase a list of dictionaries is not good or can be done differently? Im new to python, just creating a script to edit some xml documents.

So this solution works, but is it the best way that it can be done?

Comment: First of all, you have 2 lists `masterSensor` and `sensor` with just 1 dict inside of them. Iterate over 1 element lists doesn't make sense.

Comment: I add to these, they have 900 + dictionaries after reading an XML file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If every `'ItemK'` has its mate in `'SensorK'` then you could do:

```
new_dict = {}
for ik in masterSensor:
    new_dict[str(ik['ItemK'])] = {'MasterKey' : ik['MasterKey'], 'SensorId' : None}

for sk in sensor:
    new_dict[str(sk['SensorK'])]['SensorId'] = sk['SensorId']
```

This way you only have to iterate once over all elements in `masterSensor` and `sensor`.

Comment: So this is much faster, thanks. The thing is that it makes a dictionary of dictionaries. I cant figure out how to access the elements of the sub dictionary, im getting errors on my prints? `for i in new_dict:
    print ("mk %s\tsid %s" % (i['MasterKey'], i['SensorId']))`

Comment: You have to iterate over the dictionary keys: `for i in new_dict.keys(): print("mk %s\tsid %s" % (new_dict[i]['MasterKey'], new_dict[i]['SensorId']))`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help... you can simply do an intersection of values:
If you are using Python 2:

```
masterSensor.values() & sensors.values()
```

Using Python 3:

```
masterSensor = {'one': '1', 'two': '2', 'three': '3'}
sensor = {'oneone': '1', 'four': '4', 'five': '3'}
print(set(list(masterSensor.values())).intersection(set(list(sensor.values()))))
```